# NiFi Writing to HDFS Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-nifi, ambari

I am facing a problem with NiFi writing to HDFS. I am getting an error:

```
     ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS PutHDFS[id=4af43efa-a8ff-18ac-0000-00002377fba5] Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:47)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.lambda$initiateStart$1(StandardProcessorNode.java:1364)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:134)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor.getConfigurationFromResources(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:225)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor.resetHDFSResources(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:254)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor.abstractOnScheduled(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:205)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
```

My HDFS configuration is:

[image: picture of HDFS configuration]

Note: same configuration were applied on PutFile and it worked perfectly (Kafka.topic was not empty)

Comment: Can you please show your complete flow?

Answer (score 0):

It seems when **`PutHDFS`** processor is trying to save the file looking for `kafka.topic` attribute associated with the `flowfile` but attribute not having any value to it.

Make sure you are having **`kafka.topic`** attribute having `some value` associate to it, we can use [**`UpdataAttribute`**](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Can-we-add-custom-attribute-in-Apache-NiFi-on-the-fly-in-a/td-p/136681) processor before **`PutHDFS`** to add the attribute.